# What do you call the pose of a dog that has its front paws near it's head and standing on its two hind legs?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I am not sure if there's a word/expression/phrase that describes that cute pose some dogs get into to get favors. I am not even sure if dogs do get into those kind of poses, correct me if I am wrong. The only word or expression that comes to mind is cutie pose, but I doubt it means what I think it means. It's a general expression and certainly it doesn't refer to that exact pose, but I couldn't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have trained my dogs, I usually give the command "beg" for the pose you describe while offering a treat - a small biscuit or equivalent.

So I would use the word "begging".